# Command not found [[ on elementaryOS

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rvm

```
$ rvm list
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: [[: command not found
sudo: __function_on_stack: command not found

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I am getting this message when running `rvm list`. I am running the newest version of the Linux distro **elementary OS**. Any ideas why I am getting the error messages? The command, as you can see, is running correctly, but the warnings are annoying and I'd like to know why I am getting them.

Comment: Are you using `bash` as your shell?  Those complaints look like shell errors, and RVM explicitly states bash as a requirement: "Please note that RVM requires Bash, not SH, as it makes use of multiple Bash-isms that the SH shell does not support." https://rvm.io/rvm/prerequisites

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @Joe : If he has Linux, he should have bash too. Note also that this error message does **not** come from *sh*, but from *sudo*. @MarkCoates: I don't use rvm for my own work, but I guess the executable rvm is implemented as a shell script. Maybe running it with `-x` could provide some insight, i.e. `bash -x rvm list`.

Comment: @Joe, yes, I am using `bash`. I changed the tag to reflect that. I tried to provide as little as possible to make it useful to others. As it is, running the command with the trace was helpful, thanks! I piped the output to grep and realized the `[[` lines represent execution (I'm assuming) at the command line from the script and the `__function_on_stack` line is coming from a function inside the script. Regardless of what `command` was `not found`, the script is running correctly in all instances. In my normal MacBook, I never get warnings or errors.